# Combining Start-BitsTransfer with Select-String without a temporary file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to select a string in a remote file. Currently, I download the document to a temporary file and then search for my string there. I'm trying to pipe the commands together but it seems like Start-BitsTransfer needs a destination file. Can I do this without a temporary file?

```
Start-BitsTransfer -Source https://www.remoteserver/file.html -Destination C:\temp.html
$matches = Get-Content C:\temp.html -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-String '(http.*pdf)'
$matches[0].Matches.Groups[1].Value
```

Further, is it possible to output the first match in one line without having to create the variable?

Comment: the `*bits*` cmdlets are _file transfer_ cmdlets. you need to use it for files. [*grin*] ///// there is an automatic $Var named `$Matches` - you REALLY otta not use that $Var name. ///// what are you trying to achieve by NOT putting the result of `Select-String` into a $Var? if all you want is the 1st match, you can use `(Get-Content C:\file.txt | Select-String -SimpleMatch 'WordToMatch')[0].ToString()` to get the text of the 1st match found.

Comment: If bits are for file transfers, is there something better to do? Or is creating a temporary file the best way to go? $Matches came from a different post when I was learning how to isolate a part of a file: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/51478 . What I'm trying to do by not creating a file is just to simplify the code. Since all I want is to quickly access a string once, I was hoping not to find it, save it as a variable, and then read the variable.

Comment: it looks like mklement0 has posted the answer to your question. his added suggestion to get the HTML file directly seems likely to be what you want for getting a file from a web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it seems like Start-BitsTransfer needs a destination file. Can I do this without a temporary file?

No, because PowerShell has no construct that is equivalent to Bash's output process substitutions (`>(...)`)<sup>[1]</sup>, which is what you'd need here:

```
# Wishful thinking - does NOT work.
Start-BitsTransfer -Source https://www.remoteserver/file.html -Destination `
  >(Select-String '(http.*pdf)')
```

However, you can use `Invoke-RestMethod` to retrieve a text-based file such as an HTML page via HTTP and have its content output to the success stream, so you can pipe it to other commands:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -UseBasicParsing https://www.remoteserver/file.html | 
  Select-String '(http.*pdf)'
```

> is it possible to output the first match in one line without having to create the variable?

Yes, you can use a `ForEach-Object` call to extract the capture group of interest:

```
Invoke-RestMethod -UseBasicParsing https://www.remoteserver/file.html | 
  Select-String -List '(http.*pdf)' |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value }
```

Note that `-List` makes `Select-String` stop after the first line on which a match is found, i.e. after the first match in the input; omit it to find all matches in the file (one per line; to find multiple matches *per line*, add `-AllMatches`).

---

<sup>[1] Making PowerShell support process substitutions is the subject of this [feature request on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4284).</sup>